# PHP preg_match_all not returning desired output

Tags: php, string, preg-match-all

I am using preg_match_all to search a specified keyword in a string and if it found then, I pick few words before and after that keyword. I am using below preg_match_all

```
preg_match_all('~\b(?:[^ ]+ ){0,'.$prev.'}'.trim($keyword).'(?: [^ ]+){0,'.$next.'}\b~i',$text,$output);
```

here $keyword is a keyword, $prev and $next are numbers representing how many words need to pick , $text is a main string and $output are the resultant array. So if my string is below

```
PROFIT & LOSS NOFORMING P 152 22. ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: A) AUDITORS REMUNERATION (EXCLUDING SERVICE TAX) (` in crores) ParticularsCurrent yearPrevious year As audit fees (including limited review) 3.45 2.42
```

Here keyword is "Audit Fee", I get desired output, like this

```
EXCLUDING SERVICE TAX) (` in crores) ParticularsCurrent yearPrevious year As audit fees (including limited review) 3.45 2.42
```

But in a below string, where if my keyword and next word have no spaces in between it just returns few words before that string but not the next word after that keyword.

```
PROFIT & LOSS NOFORMING P 152 22. ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: A) AUDITORS REMUNERATION (EXCLUDING SERVICE TAX) (` in crores) ParticularsCurrent yearPrevious year As audit fees(including limited review) 3.45 2.42
```

It just returns

```
EXCLUDING SERVICE TAX) (` in crores) ParticularsCurrent yearPrevious year As audit fees
```

Kindly guide me here, how to get next words also if my keyword and it's next word has no space in between them.

Comment: https://www.regex101.com/r/wY6sP3/1

Comment: Hey @splash58, great work man, it worked like a charm, thank you. Post your answer, I'll select that one as correct one.

Comment: @ChangezKhan: What if you have a non-space between words before or after the keyword?

Comment: Hey @WiktorStribiżew, it doesn't matter if it have space/non-space before keyword, all I want prev & next few words, if a keyword matches in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only are worried about the words after the keyword, you need to make sure you match space characters (or non-word chars) that should be optional (zero or more):

```
'~\b(?:\S+\s+){0,10}Audit Fees(?:\s*\S+){0,5}\b~'
```

See [this regex demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/vG5lG1/4)

This will let the whitespaces between the non-whitespace chunks after the keyword optional (`\s*` matches zero or more whitespaces).

**Pattern details**:

- `\b`  - leading word boundary
- `(?:\S+\s+){0,10}`  - zero to ten 1+ non-whitespace symbols followed with 1+ whitespaces
- `Audit Fees` - literal keyword
- `(?:\s*\S+){0,5}` - zero to  five 0+ whitespace symbols followed with 1+ non-whitespace symbols
- `\b` - trailing word boundary

[PHP demo](http://ideone.com/YcZ5Fp):

```
$prev = 10;
$keyword = "Audit Fee";
$next = 5;
$text= "PROFIT & LOSS NOFORMING P 152 22. ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: A) AUDITORS REMUNERATION (EXCLUDING SERVICE TAX) (` in crores) ParticularsCurrent yearPrevious year As audit fees(including limited review) 3.45 2.42";
$re = '~\b(?:\S+\s+){0,'.$prev.'}'.trim($keyword).'(?:\s*\S+){0,'.$next.'}\b~i';
preg_match_all($re,$text,$output);
print_r($output);
```